# SQL sentence stops running on SUM() function

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to make a SQL-sentence which get a post from `test_opplegg`, and with the post I try to retrive number of votes in the table`test_thumbs`. In the table `test_thumbs`there is a column for post-id (`test_thumbs.OId`), and `test_thumbs.IntValue`. `test_thumbs.IntValue` can either be 1 or 0. And I am trying to retrieve the sum of `test_thumbs.IntValue` but when I run this code, it stops after the first post, even though the sql-sentence should print 15 posts.

```
$sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT test_opplegg.Title, test_opplegg.id as oid, test_opplegg.Desc, test_opplegg.ShortDesc,test_opplegg.Type, test_opplegg.Approved, test_opplegg.Language, test_opplegg.Grade, test_opplegg.UserId, test_opplegg.Link, test_users.id,  test_users.user_Username,  test_users.user_Name
,SUM(test_thumbs.IntValue) ExecCount
                        FROM `test_opplegg` 
                        INNER JOIN test_users ON test_opplegg.UserId = test_users.id
                        INNER JOIN test_thumbs ON test_thumbs.OId = test_opplegg.Id;
                        ;");
//$sql->bind_param('i', $id);
$sql->execute();
   $result = $sql->get_result();/* Get the result */
   $num_of_rows = $result->num_rows;/* Get the number of rows */
if ($num_of_rows > 0) { 
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $row_title = $row['Title'] ;
            $row_id = $row['oid'] ;
            $row_desc = $row['Desc'] ;
            $row_shortdesc = $row['ShortDesc'] ;
            $row_grade = $row['Grade'] ;
            $row_type = $row['Type'] ;
            $row_approved = $row['Approved'] ;
            $row_lang = strtolower($row['Language']);
            $row_uid = $row['UserId'] ;
            $row_link = $row['Link'] ;

           $row_countit = "'" . $row['ExecCount'] . "'" ;

            $row_username = $row['user_Username'] ;
            $row_name = $row['user_Name'] ;
```

If i remove `,SUM(test_thumbs.IntValue) ExecCount` everything works fine. But as soon as I write `,SUM(test_thumbs.IntValue) ExecCount` only one row is printed.

So is it possible to run the SUM()-function on every `test_opplegg.id` and for each row I also want to sum() all the values inn test_thumbs with the same post-id.

Comment: Some formatting would be nice

Comment: Is the formatting relevant?
If i remove `,SUM(test_thumbs.IntValue) ExecCount` everything works fine. But as soon as I write `,SUM(test_thumbs.IntValue) ExecCount` only one row is printed.

Comment: `,SUM(test_thumbs.IntValue) ExecCount` seems a bit weird though. Have you tried `SUM(the_value) AS my_value` ? EDIT: and/or a comma too I guess

Comment: `,SUM(test_thumbs.IntValue) ExecCount` works at the same way as `,SUM(test_thumbs.IntValue) AS ExecCount`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you miss

```
group by test_opplegg.Id
```

In the query

UPDATE:

So change the JOIN to

```
LEFT JOIN test_thumbs ON test_thumbs.OId = test_opplegg.Id
```

Thus if there is no corresponding records in `test_thumbs` the the sum is 0

Comment: You are right, but now it seems like it only prints out post that have a value in `test_thumbs`. So if noone have voted for the post, you can not see it.

Comment: Thank you very much! :-)